# How to get count value from two table using alias name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, one `export_log` and another one is `client_log` table first I tried to get `count` value from single table(`export_log`) which worked correctly. And then I tried to get `count` value from two tables(`export_log` and `client log`), now I have an error like :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '* ) Total_login, cl.count(*) Total_access DATE_FORMAT( max(
>   `el.lastmodified` ) ' at line 1

I need to get `count` value from two tables with single query, I have tried so many times I didn't get the results. And also how to use alias name inside max() function?

pls correct this query..

```
 SELECT el.count( * ) Total_login, cl.count(*) Total_access DATE_FORMAT( max( `el.lastmodified` ) , '%d %M %y ,%H:%i' ) last_logged
    FROM export_log el, client_log cl
    WHERE (el.unique_id = 'n110r24dan756j5vnv5v0016r31ad6jg' and el.unique_id != 'nn10r24daj756j5hnv5v0016r31ad6ja') AND (cl.unique_id = 'n110r24dan756j5vnv5v0016r31ad6jg' and cl.unique_id != 'n110r24dan756j5vnv5v0016r31ad6jg')
    AND el.user_name
    IN (
    'bala','sathish'
    ) AND cl.user_name IN('bala','sathish')
    AND `el.lastmodified`>=CAST(DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-01' ) AS DATE)and CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE)
    GROUP BY el.unique_id,cl.unique_id
    ORDER BY Total_login DESC
```

Comment: Count(el.user_name) is a good start. Since el.coubt(*) is wrong syntax

Comment: Or count(el.id) whatever is your primary key for the login table :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your syntax is wrong at **select** clause so you can try:

```
SELECT count(el.*) Total_login, count(cl.*) Total_access, DATE_FORMAT( max(`el.lastmodified`) , '%d %M %y ,%H:%i') last_logged
    FROM export_log el, client_log cl
    WHERE (el.unique_id = 'n110r24dan756j5vnv5v0016r31ad6jg' and el.unique_id != 'nn10r24daj756j5hnv5v0016r31ad6ja') AND (cl.unique_id = 'n110r24dan756j5vnv5v0016r31ad6jg' and cl.unique_id != 'n110r24dan756j5vnv5v0016r31ad6jg')
    AND el.user_name
    IN (
    'bala','sathish'
    ) AND cl.user_name IN('bala','sathish')
    AND `el.lastmodified`>=CAST(DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-01' ) AS DATE)and CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE)
    GROUP BY el.unique_id,cl.unique_id
    ORDER BY Total_login DESC
```

Comment: After i changed your suggestion again i get error sir, that error is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* ) Total_login, count(cl.*) Total_access, DATE_FORMAT( max( `el.lastmodified` )' at line 1

Comment: You should delete space at count(el.*) Total_login